# How can I use special chars in VBA of Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a set of macro files in Microsoft Word's VBA as a sort of a CAT tool (CAT = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation). The problem is that there are cases where I display the text needed to be translated and the user needs to input text in his own language. That might include some special chars, like "ăîâșț/ĂÎÂȘȚ", or even quotes or brackets. Is there any way to use those in some `InputBox` function? Or, at least, some way to let the user input the text he needs in some `TextBox` or something?... Or how should I approach this?... Maybe UTF-8 support would be what I need? Or?... Any help would be appreciated!...

I've tried Microsoft Word's vba function `InputBox`. I'm also thinking if, maybe, I would be able to create my own `InputBox`, with my conditions on it, I might be able to have one that accepts those chars too, or all the chars into some string variable... Here is something someone on StackOverflow says:
[Is it possible to create an 'input box' in VBA that can take a text selection with multiple lines as an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345287/is-it-possible-to-create-an-input-box-in-vba-that-can-take-a-text-selection-wi) (I'm referring to gizlmo's answer...)

Here are 3 lines of code that contain that (although it's more of a how to question, not a debugging question, so those are not really needed...)

```vb
MsgBox ("Ziua " & Str(ziua) & " - " & titlurien(ziua))
        titluales = InputBox("Titlul original:  " & titlurien(ziua), "Ziua: " & Str(ziua) & ", Rapsodia Realitatilor " & monthname(lunanecesara) & Str(annecesar))
        titluriro(ziua) = titluales
```

I expect the output to be exactly what he typed, whether it's quotes, brackets or special characters (like "ăîâșț"/"ĂÎÂȘȚ")...

Answer (score 0):

A VBA InputBox will take any character typed or pasted into it. The characters available to type depends on the Language version of Windows and Office that the end user has installed.

Below is a test I just made with your example character string "ăîâșț/ĂÎÂȘȚ"

```
SpecialCharInput()
    Dim str As String
    str = InputBox("Enter you text", "Special Test Input Box")
    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

On my English language system, the only trouble it had was with the upper and lower case "ȘȚ" Turkish characters. By trouble I mean it turned those characters into question marks "??" in the result string. I'm sure though, if my system supported the Turkish language that those characters would be recognized and outputted properly.

Comment: That is the exact problem. It displays those question marks for me too (and I do have the language installed. By the way, it's the Romanian language, not the Turkish language). Also - sometimes the user has to input quotation marks too or brackets etc (just to keep in mind, in case some other method is used, it has to support those too...)
So... no, those characters are not recognized nor outputted properly... but thanks for your try.